# can't send an Email by liferay

Tags: java, liferay

```
try {
    InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress("tehilar20@gmail.com");
    InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("tehilar20@gmail.com");
    String sub = new String("test");
    String body = new String("test-mail");
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.setTo(to);
    msg.setFrom(from);
    msg.setBody(body);
    msg.setSubject(sub);
    MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(msg);
    MailEngine.send(from, to, sub, body);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("can't send mail");
}
```

```
MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(msg);
```

that way just not works

```
MailEngine.send(from, to, sub, body);
```

that way gives me that Error:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the authentication properties, check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) for complete examples.

Comment: thank you, I already try to set my SMTP properties by ROOT.xml and by the control panel, do you have another idea?

Comment: @user1075116 Where do you set username and password? Does one of the examples work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is you are connecting using the SMTP protocol without SSL. If this is JavaMail-based, make sure you use the smtps protocol as that is SMTP with SSL. Also make sure you enable authentication. See the [JavaMail FAQ entry on GMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#gmail)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check "Use a Secure Network Connection" under "Outgoing SMTP Server" on mail configuration page?

You could also try setting "Manually specify additional JavaMail properties to override the above configuration." to

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```

Comment: As JavaMail has a separate smtps protocol provider to take care of SMTP using SSL, specifying a separate socketFactory for SSL is no longer necessary (not since JavaMail 1.2 or 1.3 I believe).

Answer (score 1):

to send email from Liferay I recommend the use of the Message Bus. There are two destination ad hoc for this purpose. You can find a complete example on my [GitHub](https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-messagebus-subscribe-example) repository. A follow a piece of sample code that uses the class SubscriptionSender which in turn makes use of the Message Bus.

```
            SubscriptionSender subscriptionSender = new SubscriptionSender();

        subscriptionSender.setSubject("Lista degli utenti disattivati");
        subscriptionSender.setBody(emailBody.toString());
        subscriptionSender.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        subscriptionSender.setCompanyId(user.getCompanyId());
        subscriptionSender.setFrom("noreply@liferay.com", "Liferay Portal");
        subscriptionSender.setHtmlFormat(false);
        subscriptionSender.setMailId("user", user.getUserId());

        subscriptionSender.addRuntimeSubscribers(
            user.getEmailAddress(),
            user.getFullName());

        List<EmailAddress> emails = (List<EmailAddress>) user.getEmailAddresses();
        if (emails.size() > 0) {
            if (_log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                _log.info("User " + user.getUserId() +
                    " has additional emails address");
            }
            for (EmailAddress emailAddress : emails) {
                subscriptionSender.addRuntimeSubscribers(
                    emailAddress.getAddress(),
                    (String) user.getFullName());

            }
        }

        subscriptionSender.flushNotificationsAsync();
```

You can find the complete source at [SendMail.java](https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-messagebus-subscribe-example/blob/master/src/main/java/it/dontesta/liferay/messagebus/example/mvc/SendEmail.java)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a GMail configuration in portal-ext.properties that worked for me for years:

```
mail.session.mail.pop3.host=localhost
mail.session.mail.pop3.password=
mail.session.mail.pop3.port=110
mail.session.mail.pop3.user=
mail.session.mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.session.mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.session.mail.smtp.port=465
mail.session.mail.smtp.password=<MY-PASSWORD-ON-GMAIL>
mail.session.mail.smtp.user=<MY-USERNAME-ON-GMAIL-(WITHOUT-@GMAIL.COM)>
mail.session.mail.store.protocol=pop3
mail.session.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.session.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.session.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```